# My apk run in debug mode successfully but release apk not run has crash or show stack trace in release mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My apk run in debug mode successfully but release apk not run has crash or show stack trace in release mode
When i select video from gallery and trim app has crash and show error

```
Build version: 1.0 

Current date: 2020-12-06 16:45:01 
Device: Micromax Q4310 
OS version: Android 7.0 (SDK 24) 
 
Stack trace:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox
    at e.d.a.h.a()
    at e.d.a.b.a()
    at e.i.a.e.next()
    at e.i.a.e.hasNext()
    at e.i.a.c.e.hasNext()
    at e.d.a.e.p()
    at e.i.a.a.b.a.a.a()
    at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.b.b.a()
    at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.b.b.a()
    at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.b.a()
    at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.b.a$a.run()
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yaadein.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.yaadein.app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.yaadein.app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to do with Proguard hiding your classes.

Have a look at modifying your Proguard rules file to prevent this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code) or set minifyEnabled to false in your app-level build.gradle file.